# Combining multiple SPF records - SenderID - kind of lost

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, email

Tried to read up on SPF record creating but I am a bit lost.

I need to combine and create an SPF record because our email is not getting through.

Here are the ways we send email:

1. Daily newsletter emails are currently sent using Constant Contact. 
   So we need to show that they are authorized to send on our behalf. Here is their support article (note, we do not self authenticate)  http://support2.constantcontact.com/articles/FAQ/1768
2. Transactional emails are all sent using Mandril.
   http://help.mandrill.com/entries/22030056-How-do-I-add-DNS-records-for-my-sending-domains-
3. We use Google apps to send our own emails to customers and our sales team, etc.
4. My domain is registered with GoDaddy and this is where I will be uploading the record.

Can you help me organize SPF and SenderID?

Comment: What is your current nonworking SPF record?

Answer (score 2):

This tool should hep you construct what you need: http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/

SenderID should work off of v=spf1 records these days, but if CTCT doesn't like that enough, use toggle the last option box from "both" to the one that mentions "pra" and create a second text record with that.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't bother with SenderID, just use SPF.
Probably adding this TXT record to your domain is enough.

```
v=spf1 include:spf.constantcontact.com include:spf.mandrillapp.com a include:_spf.google.com ~all
```